# Unable to resolve module - importing Redux in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

Just added Redux to my app and it's saying it cant find my store. Is this a bug in React? I've worked with Vue2 and Angular2, but I'm a total noob when it comes to all things React.
[image]

Here's a screenshot of my structure and main js file...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reference is `configStore`, your file name is `configureStore.js`. Change them to match each other.

Comment: All good - happens to all of us. I'm a serial offender of having a default export, then importing using `{ myExport }` - which of course doesn't work either, and is just as confusing of an error. Best of luck.